# Select/Highlight column range (A-L) for every specific cell values ('Apple') in every row

Tags: excel

I'm trying to find an easy way to get rid of 'bad' rows in my worksheet, which has 3780 rows. Instead of scanning through and deleting each rows every time, which is time consuming, I was wondering if there was an easier way?

Perhaps by making a macro that highlights cells in a column range (A-L) every time it finds the bad value (e.g. 'Apple') in a cell located in every row.

Something along the lines of:

```
If =ISTEXT() then delete row
```

I hope this makes sense, let me know if not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This small macro will search for the presence of *apple* in any cell in columns **A** through **L** and delete that row:

```
Sub KillBadApple()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("A:L"))

    nLastRow = rng.Rows.Count + rng.Row - 1
    nFirstRow = rng.Row

    For i = nLastRow To nFirstRow Step -1
        exam = ""
        For j = 1 To 12
            exam = exam & Chr(1) & Cells(i, j).Text
        Next j

        exam = LCase(exam)
        If InStr(exam, "apple") > 0 Then
            Cells(i, j).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```